# Beautiful Soup error: NameError: name 'htmltext' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm getting this error:

```
NameError: name 'htmltext' is not defined
```

It comes from the code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib.parse

url = "http://nytimes.com"

urls = [url]
visited = [url]

while len(urls) > 0:
        try:
           htmltext = urllib.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
        except:
           print(urls[0])      

        soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)    
        urls.pop(0)

        print(soup.findAll('a',href = true))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.x, you have to import `urllib.request` instead of `urllib`. Then, change the line:

```
htmltext = urllib.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
```

to:

```
htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
```

Finally, change `true` to `True`.

Comment: In the event that the `try` block fails and the `except` block is executed, the call to `BeautifulSoup` with the `htmltext` argument will cause problems. Maybe add the rest of the code to the `try` block?

Comment: You're right, it's probably best to include more error handling in case, for instance, the url is invalid. As is, the changes I recommend would work for this particular case, but I do agree it could be improved even further.

Comment: Thanks all. That was really helpful I had assumed that Beautiful soup was installed incorrectly, but I see now that syntax can be tricky with python. Thanks again.